# Check if div exists outside span jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to check if a div (without ID) exists after a textarea with jQuery.

```
<span dir="none"> 
  <textarea title="Name" class="ms-long" id="textArea" rows="6" cols="20">
  </textarea>
  <br>
</span>

<div>     <-----
  <span>
   SPAN WITH TEXT
  </span>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
 jQuery('#textArea').next('div').length;
```

But this gives me length = 0. What am I doing wrong here? Is it because the textarea is inside a span?

Comment: `jQuery('#textArea').parent().next('div').length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `div` is next to `parent` of `textArea`, So you need `.parent()` to traverse up to its parent i.e. `span` then you can use `.next()`

```
jQuery('#textArea').parent().next('div').length
```

Answer (score 1):

textarea is not sibling of div element, its parent span is. Thus you need to traverse to span element and then find next div element:

```
jQuery('#textArea').parent().next('div').length;
```